# jquery live & livequery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, livequery

I'm using jquery's load to bring in thumbnails via ajax. I'd like to user to be able to hover over the cropped thumb to view a small uncropped version of the image using [imgPreview plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/new-jquery-plugin-imgpreview/). If they click on it, then bring up the full sized image in a lightbox ([fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)).

For the lightbox, I have:

```
$("ul#plant_gallery li a").livequery( function(){   
    $(this).fancybox ({ 'overlayOpacity': 0.9, 'overlayColor': '#000', });
});
```

And for the tooltip uncropped image hover, I have:

```
$('ul#plant_gallery li a').live('mouseover', function()
{
    if (!$(this).data('init'))
    {
        $(this).data('init', true);
        $(this).imgPreview({imgCSS: { width: 200 }, srcAttr: 'rel'})
        (
            function()
            {

            },

            function()
            {
            }
        );
        $(this).trigger('mouseover');
    }
});
```

How can I combine these two into one? Should I be using either jquery's live or livequery? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by combining these two? If you want to respond to different events (hover and click), you'll need two separate functions to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't NEED to combine them, have you tried:

```
$("ul#plant_gallery li a").live('click', function(){   
    $(this).fancybox ({ 'overlayOpacity': 0.9, 'overlayColor': '#000', });
});
```

And leaving the other function as it is?